# xxhash - how to calculate from the Windows command-line?

Tags: windows, command-line, checksum

Is there a way to calculate a xxhash hash from the command-line in Windows?

I have searched everywhere to find a checksum utility that supports the xxhash algorithm - the only utility I could find was rahash2.exe from the [Radare framework](https://github.com/radare/radare2/wiki/Rahash2), but it is 32-bit only (so no files > 2GB) and doesn't seem to work properly on my workstations (no output of the checksum).

Is there another solution to allow me to calculate a xxhash checksum for a file, **without installing additional frameworks or dependencies**?

Comment: How does 32-bitness correlate with "2 GB max" "limitation"?

Comment: @AntonGogolev: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_GB_limit -- apparently when you use 32-bit architecture you run into limits with files bigger than 2GB. I tried to use rahash2.exe with a 6GB file initially, only to get an error warning "file size unknown", while using a 1GB file didn't give any errors.

Comment: The xxhash project page includes a `Makefile` build script to compile `xxhsum` on any target, including `mingw` on Windows.
The binary itself has no special dependency, but building it requires `mingw`. So, if you are not familiar with `mingw`, this can be difficult.
Alternatively, if you prefer Visual, you can just include the 3 source code files in a console project, and compile.

Comment: @Cyan : There's an older version of xxHash compiled for Windows here: [xxHash v0.6.2](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash/releases/tag/v0.6.2), which seems to work fine. But it would be nice if someone would post instructions on how to compile the current version in Windows. (It's easy to compile in Linux, but in Windows, someone like me not familiar with C, Windows and Mingw couldn't "make" it :-) )

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options, apparently, one of them would be to run the MINGW shell and install this package:

https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-xxhash